# SQL stored procedure with 3 tables

Tags: sql, plsql

I have the following tables linked here: [tables](http://textuploader.com/tpix).

What I have is here: [procedure](http://textuploader.com/tpif).

I need to list all projects and tasks belonging to a given customer (customer number given as a parameter). At the beginning of the report show the customer name followed by the first project, displaying the project and name. For each project display beneath it the task number (in ascending order), description, hours and start date. Follow the last task with the customer’s total number of tasks and project charges then do the same for each subsequent project for the customer.  At the end of the report, give the total number of hours for that all the tasks, as well as how many projects and tasks were reported.

I'm not really sure how procedures work so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the issue with your current output? Also, you should add a tag for PL/SQL.

Comment: Well I need it to display column headers which I don't have. I also need it to display the total number of tasks for each project as well as the total hours for each project. And then at the end of the report, I need the total number of projects, total number of tasks, and total number of hours.

Comment: Also, I need it to show all tasks for a project, which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Do you have a working query that returns the records you want the report to display? I suggest you start there. Once you have the results you need then outputting the data is simple.

Comment: +1 for including (via the links) sufficient information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `nextproject` cursor has no relationship defined between TASK and either of the other tables used in the cursor, so every row in TASK is being joined to all the valid combinations of PROJECT and CUSTOMER. This is known as a "Cartesian join" and is probably not what you had in mind. To correct this you need modify the cursor slightly:

```
cursor nextproject is
  select p.pjno, c.custname, t.taskno, t.descrip, t.hrs, t.start_date
    from task T, project P, customer C
    where C.custno = P.custno and
          p.custno = custnum
      AND t.pjno = p.pjno;  -- ADDED
```

This may or may not fix all your problems, but it should move you along with this assignment.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9c564/5) for those who care to take a stab at it.

Share and enjoy.